# Local ring and its dimension, how can i prove this?

Tags: commutative-algebra

My textbook says:
Let
$A$: Local ring with the unique maximal ideal $m$,
$d:=\dim A$
then
$f_1, f_2,\ldots,f_d \in m$, $m=\sqrt{(f_1,\ldots,f_d)} \iff \dim A/(f_1,...f_d)=0$.

How can I prove this? What I could understand was $\dim R=0$ implies that any prime ideal of $R$ is also a maximal ideal....

Comment: What does the right side of the if and only mean? The dimension of A is a number and the bottom is an ideal?

Comment: yes! I still don't think this is obvious...

Comment: Does $n={}{}d$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown What is the "n"?

Comment: @ciatina That is what I am asking you: the $n$ appears in $A/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, sorry typo

Comment: I still don’t get what it means to take a number (divided by? Quotient by?) an ideal

Comment: @PrinceM $\dim A/(f_1,\ldots,f_d)$ is the dimension of the ring $A/(f_1,\ldots,f_d)$.

Comment: Ok! That makes sense

Comment: Isn't this obvious? Since the radical $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of all primes containing $I$, you get $\dim(A/I)=\dim(A/\mathfrak{m})$ which is zero because $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field. (Here, $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_d)$.) Note, if you take $d$ minimal, then $\dim(A)=d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and $I$ be an ideal such that $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak{m}$. The ideal $I$ is known as a *parameter ideal for $R$*.

$\Rightarrow$: We have $\dim R/I=0$. Indeed, it is clear that $\dim R/I=\dim R/\mathfrak{m}=0$ since $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field and by **1**.

$\Leftarrow$: Let $J\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ be an ideal such that $\dim R/J=0$. Every minimal prime in $R/J$ is maximal. Since $R$ is local, it follows that $\mathfrak{m}/J$ is the unique minimal prime ideal of $R/J$. Hence, we have $\sqrt{J}=\mathfrak{m}$ and $J$ is a parameter ideal for $R$.

**1.** I repeatedly used the fact that for a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ in $R$, we have
$$
\sqrt{I}=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\colon\text{ prime containing }I}\mathfrak{p}=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\colon\text{ minimal prime containing }I}\mathfrak{p}\,.
$$

**2.** If $R$ is a local noetherian ring, then the minimal number of generators of a parameter ideal is equal to the dimension of $R$. If we choose $\dim R$ generators of a parameter ideal, they are called a *system of parameters for $R$*.